# How do I communicate variables between methods in Python?

Tags: python

I am a beginner. I wrote some code that I'm now trying to organize into methods, but I don't understand at all how Python communicates between methods. The outline of my code is as follows:
[pseudocode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byRxg.png)

Note, everything worked fine when it was all together, but now I'm having trouble transferring the array from Method 1 to Method 2. No matter what I do, something or other is always undefined. Also, running the second method always requires more arguments, which I don't understand. 
Right now, the current code I have below is returning:

> NameError: name 'csvGet' is not defined

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
# Ask for csv file path and define
file_in = input('READ FILE: ')
# Get browser driver path
chromeDriver_Path = '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/chromedriver'

class App:  
    def __init__(self, file_in):
        # Initialize csv file path
        self.file_in = file_in
        # Initialize browser driver path
        self.chromeDriver_Path = chromeDriver_Path

    # Inject csv file
    def csvGet(self):
        # Declare array for urls
        urls = []
        # Open csv file from path
        with open(file_in, 'r') as f:
            # Read csv file
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            # Add each row in column 11 of csv to urls array
            for row in reader:
                urls.append(row[11])
        # Skip first row in array
        urls = urls[1:]
        # Return the array
        return urls

    # Run automatic browser
    def goBrowser(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options = Options()
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromeDriver_Path, chrome_options=options)

        # Get array from other method
        urls = csvGet(urls)

        cnt = 0

        for link in urls:
            cnt += 1
            browser.get(link)
            # Do more stuff...

        browser.quit()

     goBrowser(csvGet)
```

Explain like I'm five: What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need `urls = self.csvGet(urls)`, but it gives another error because you haven't added `urls` argument in `csvGet` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App is a `class`, so instead of `goBrowser(csvGet)`, you need to create an instance of App and call its methods as follows:

```
app = App()
app.goBrowser()
```

Second, in the `goBrowser()` function you need to call `csvGet()`. Again, since it's in a class you need the following syntax:

```
self.csvGet()
```

Basically, `self` is a special argument which gets passed to each method - when you call `app.goBrowser()` it calls `goBrowser()`, passing `self=app`. In other object-orientated languages like C++ or C# this is hidden but in Python, it's exposed.

Edit: Also as shaik moeed says, csvGet() is missing the urls argument, i.e.

```
def csvGet(self, urls):
    pass

...
self.csvGet(urls)
```

Comment: Thank you! Also, I needed to declare another urls array in goBrowser() to finally get everything to work.

Comment: Glad I can help

Answer (score 0):

self is best for passing any type of variable while you using object oriented programming
Code like:
    if **name** == "**main**":
    file_in = input('READ FILE: ')chromeDriver_Path='/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/chromedriver'

```
class App:  
    def __init__(self, file_in, screenshotFolder):
    # Initialize csv file path
    self.file_in = file_in
    # Initialize browser driver path
    self.chromeDriver_Path = chromeDriver_Path

    # Inject csv file
    def csvGet(self):
        # Declare array for urls
        urls = []
        # Open csv file from path
        with open(file_in, 'r') as f:
            # Read csv file
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            # Add each row in column 11 of csv to urls array
            for row in reader:
                urls.append(row[11])
        # Skip first row in array
        urls = urls[1:]
        # Return the array
        return urls

    # Run automatic browser
    def goBrowser(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options = Options()
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromeDriver_Path, chrome_options=options)

        # Get array from other method
        urls = self.csvGet(urls)

        cnt = 0

        for link in urls:
            cnt += 1
            browser.get(link)
            # Do more stuff...

        browser.quit()

     goBrowser(self)
```